# subsetting values in a zoo with multiple time-series (columns)

Tags: r, zoo

I am trying to substitute -Inf for NA in a multi column zoo. However when I tried to subset the values that are -Inf in the zoo object the way I would do for a matrix it does not work and therefore the substitution cannot be made:

```
library(zoo)
mat = matrix(1:50, ncol = 5)
mat[2,5]=-Inf
mat[8,3]=-Inf
colnames(mat) = letters[1:5]

z = as.zoo(mat)

mat[is.infinite(mat)] = NA
mat

z[is.infinite(z)]= NA
z
```

I can do this with a loop but it seems like it should not be necessary to use a loop for something so basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logical subscripting will refer to the index. Instead do it this way:

```
z[] <- ifelse(is.infinite(z), NA, z)
```

or if you want to assign it to a different variable the rhs would be:

```
z * ifelse(is.infinite(z), NA, 1)
```

This also works:

```
coredata(z)[is.infinite(z)] <- NA
```